# Merge n input objects in jq

Tags: json, object, merge, jq

I have two JSON input files that I want to merge recursively:

`file1.json`

```json
{
  "key1": {
    "key1.1": "foo",
    "key1.2": "bar"
  },
  "key2": {
    "key2.1": "daz"
  }
}
```

`file2.json`

```json
{
  "key1": {
    "key1.3": "dingo"
  },
  "key2": {
    "key2.2": "lorem"
  }
}
```

I know I can combine these two with `--slurp` and the `*` operator:

```sh
jq --slurp '.[0] * .[1]' file1.json file2.json
```

```json
{
  "key1": {
    "key1.1": "foo",
    "key1.2": "bar",
    "key1.3": "dingo"
  },
  "key2": {
    "key2.1": "daz",
    "key2.2": "lorem"
  }
}
```

And of course I can do this with any number of files, as long as I know the exact number of input files. However, how can the `'.[0] * .[1]'` part be generalised to work with an arbitrary number of input files?

For the `+` operator I could do `'. | add'`, but `+` isn't what I want. Is there an equivalent to `add` for `*`?

Answer (score 1):

```
jq --slurp '.[0] * .[1]' file1.json file2.json
```

Could be replaced with a [`reduce`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Reduce) to match `n` files:

```
jq 'reduce inputs as $i (.; . * $i)' file1.json file2.json
```

---

To test this, lets add `file3.json` with the following content:

```json
{
  "key7": {
    "key7.3": "dingo"
  },
  "key8": {
    "key8.2": "lorem"
  }
}
```

Changing the command to include a wildcard (`*`) (lazy...):

```
jq 'reduce inputs as $i (.; . * $i)' file*.json
```

Gives the following output:

```json
{
  "key1": {
    "key1.1": "foo",
    "key1.2": "bar",
    "key1.3": "dingo"
  },
  "key2": {
    "key2.1": "daz",
    "key2.2": "lorem"
  },
  "key7": {
    "key7.3": "dingo"
  },
  "key8": {
    "key8.2": "lorem"
  }
}
```